# How to Make a Matrix Function?

Tags: matrix, function-construction

I have six vectors defined like this:

```
r1 = {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)};
r2 = {1/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)};
r3= {1, 0};
r4 = {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2};
r5 = {-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2};
r6 = {-1, 0};
```

Now I can create a function matrix `Ht` from these.

```
Ht = ConstantArray[0, {24, 24}];
Ht[[1, 20]] = Exp[I k.(r1-r2)];
Ht[[19, 2]] = -Exp[I k.(r1-r2)];
Ht[[3, 22]] = Exp[I k.(r3-r4)];
Ht[[21, 4]] = -Exp[I k.(r3-r4)];
Ht[[5, 24]] = Exp[I k.(r5-r6)];
Ht[[23, 6]] = -Exp[I k.(r5 - r6)];
```

Now I need a `H1` which would be a function of 'k'. Something like:

```
H1[k_] := Ht
```

Is it possible?? Please help.

Comment: Use `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`).  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487

Comment: Ok .... thanks. I got it

Comment: Did you read the post I linked to?  Please be specific about what you are doing.  `H1[k_] = Ht` creates a function in terms of `k`.  `Clear[H1]`  first if there are previous definitions.

Comment: I read the link and did `H1[k_]=Ht` and it worked, Thanks Szabolcs